# NSMutableArray Sorting Issue

Tags: objective-c, arrays, sorting

In my main file, I define NSMutableArray *creditList;

In my loop (that increments myCount until finished) to populate the array with movie information from the JSON response, I have:

```
creditType = fetchedData[@"cast"][myCount][@"media_type"];
creditTitle = fetchedData[@"cast"][myCount][@"title"];
creditCharacter = fetchedData[@"cast"][myCount][@"character"];
creditReleasedate = fetchedData[@"cast"][myCount][@"release_date"];
creditReleasedate = fetchedData[@"cast"][myCount][@"release_date"];
```

The array populates as you would expect, but now it needs to be sorted by release date.

I have tried:

```
NSSortDescriptor *ageDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"release_date" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[ageDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArrayByReleaseYear = [creditList sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

However when the code runs, as soon as it gets to the sorting code I get:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x7ca30db0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key release_date.'
```

I have tried other sorting methods from this site but I can't seem to get any of them to run without errors.  Extra kudos points to whomever can help thanks!

Comment: You don't show what is in `creditList`, but from the error, `creditList` is an array of `NSStrings`, so it can't be sorted by 'release_date'.

Comment: Basically it is telling you that the class `NSString` does not have a property called `release_date`. You are sorting an array of strings, when perhaps you expect the elements to be some of other sort of custom class or dictionary.

Comment: Here is how I defined the strings:
                NSString *creditType = @"";
                NSString *creditTitle = @"";
                NSString *creditCharacter = @"";
                NSString *creditReleasedate = @"";
                NSString *creditPosterpath = @"";

Comment: Here is part of the JSON:

    {
    cast =     (
                {
            adult = 0;
            character = Bacon;
            "credit_id" = 52fe4217c3a36847f8003607;
            id = 100;
            "media_type" = movie;
            "original_title" = "Lock, Stock and Two Smoking Barrels";
            "poster_path" = "/9WObtE3uqnVAt9hLSK0qtwh9Izd.jpg";
            "release_date" = "1998-03-05";
            title = "Lock, Stock and Two Smoking Barrels";
        }

Comment: What would be a better way to achieve a sorted list?  :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you define a class to represent your data, e.g. `XYZMovie` that inherits from `NSObject`. Then add `creditType`, `creditTitle` etc. as properties to that class. (It do not need to have any code, just properties)

Instantiate and fill new such objects from your json data in your loop and then insert them into the `NSMutableArray`.

With that setup your sort method with predicates will work. The predicate looks to sort the objects in the array based on one of their properties. With the current setup there is no information to tell which `NSString` entries in the array are of what kind and which belong together.

---

**Edit:** Added reply to second comment below (my stupid web browser at work do not allow adding comment)
I can see from your notation you are used to c style array notation. This is for byte vectors with pointer references. that do not work with `NSArrays`, they are not vectors like that and cannot be treated as multidimensional with `[ ][ ]` notation. Your second try is very close. The inner part of that returns your data object  (`[creditList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`) but then you cannot enumerate the properties by number. Instead they are referenced by name like so:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[creditList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] propertyName];
```

where `propertyName` is the name you gave the property you want to display, for example `movieTitle` or `mainActor`.

Comment: Thanks I will try that - even if I set creditReleasedate as type NSDate, would I not be able to sort using that with the existing code?

Comment: Ok I did that and I now have a sorted list in array creditList (as seen when I hover over 'creditList' when I add a breakpoint, but it's not clear to me how to put the data from it into the table cell.

I tried:
cell.textLabel.text = creditList[0][0];

and:
cell.textLabel.text = [creditList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0];

but both error out.  I feel like I am so close now, I can see the finish line!

Comment: This answer is correct; using a custom object is worth the effort, but it fails to mention that you must use the correct data types to represent the data.  If `release_date` is a date then it must be represented using `NSDate` not `NSString`.  This goes for other properties of the object.